# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"UnexpectedEof"'

Tags: typescript, deno

Getting this error when compiling my deno app:

```
$ deno compile --allow-all --unstable --output ./app ./index.ts
Check file:///home/ubuntu/www/iptvfish/iptvfish-api/index.ts
error: TS2416 [ERROR]: Property 'name' in type 'PartialReadError' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'UnexpectedEof'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"UnexpectedEof"'.
  name = "PartialReadError";
  ~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.74.0/io/bufio.ts:27:3
TS2416 [ERROR]: Property 'name' in type 'PartialReadError' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'UnexpectedEof'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"UnexpectedEof"'.
  name = "PartialReadError";
  ~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/io/bufio.ts:27:3

Found 2 errors.
```

```
$ deno -V
deno 1.13.0
```

code worked before i upgraded deno

Comment: Are you importing `std/io/bufio` directly or is it being imported by another dependency? The std library is versioned alongside Deno and each new version of the std library is guaranteed to work with that version of Deno. (It is not necessarily backward compatible.) You can try updating that dependency to the compatible version: `https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/io/bufio.ts` if you control the imports, or you can use an [import map](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.0/linking_to_external_code/import_maps) to map the older version specifiers to the current one.

Comment: must be either oak ot denodb using it. i'm not importing it.

Comment: I've had to use the import map method for some sub dependencies which rely on version-specific semantics of properties of the `Deno` namespace, and it solved similar issues for me. If this ends up working for you, or you need more detail, I will create a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its a bug with the mysql driver and 1.13.0 of deno (fixed but denodb hasn't released their patch yet).

For the time being you can do this:

```
// import { Database, SQLite3Connector } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts';
import { Database, SQLite3Connector } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stillalivx/denodb/master/mod.ts';
```

Comment: I would suggest using a specific commit ID in the raw githubuser content URL to avoid having breaking changes pulled from the master branch, but yeah pulling straight from github is a great solution to this problem!